# Why does importing numpy add 1 GB of virtual memory on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, numpy

I have to run python in a resource constrained environment with only a few GB of virtual memory. Worse yet, I have to fork children from my main process as part of application design, all of which receive a copy-on-write allocation of this same amount of virtual memory on fork. The result is that after forking only 1 - 2 children, the process group hits the ceiling and shuts everything down. Finally, I am not able to remove numpy as a dependency; it is a strict requirement.

Any advice on how I can bring this initial memory allocation down?

e.g.

1. Change the default amount allocated to numpy on import?
2. Disable the feature and force python / numpy to allocate more dynamically?

Details:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
Python 3.6.2
numpy>=1.13.3

Bare Interpreter:

```
import os
os.system('cat "/proc/{}/status"'.format(os.getpid()))

# ... VmRSS: 7300 kB
# ... VmData: 4348 kB
# ... VmSize: 129160 kB

import numpy
os.system('cat "/proc/{}/status"'.format(os.getpid()))

# ... VmRSS: 21020 kB
# ... VmData: 1003220 kB
# ... VmSize: 1247088 kB
```

Comment: I don't notice such drastic jumps with my system, but it does shoot up by 200MB when I import the module

Comment: May I ask how you do the forking? Are you calling `os.fork` or are you using `multiprocessing`?

Comment: multiprocessing via concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: I suggest you switch to using python's multiprocessing module, unless you are bound to using the concurrent module. Switching allows you to [`spawn processes rather than forking them`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). Also, dropping a [ticket](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) in the numpy repo to let them know, and maybe they could provide some guidance. It could be that numpy does not behave with multiprocessing

Comment: The behavior on fork seems reasonable to me. My primary concern is why on import numpy has so much memory allocated to the process by default. I think this feature of numpy would make it so that spawning would have the same effect, no? Your advice to raise ticket is good idea I will do that.

Comment: Thanks for filing [the numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10455)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, skullgoblet1089, for raising questions on SO and at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10455 , and for answering.
Citing your 2018-01-24 post:

Reducing threads with `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` will bring down VM allocation.